# Google Client fails to verify token on back-end server

Tags: php, android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I have downloaded project from [Try Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start), created project on Google API Console. I have successfully configured `signin` project and run the application in the emulator. I pasted OAuth Web Client ID into `strings.xml`. Then opened this `IdTokenActivity` and got `idToken`.

I copied this token and created request using POSTMAN to my server `http://localhost/api/googlesignin/hello`

On server I have this code:

```
public function hello(Request $request)
{
    $idToken = $request->get('idToken');
    $client = new \Google_Client([
        'client_id' => '[SAME CLIENT ID AS THE ONE IN STRINGS.XML]'
    ]);

    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($idToken);
    var_dump($payload)
}
```

But this returns `FALSE` meaning it fails to verify `$idToken`.
But using endpoint token verification like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={$idToken}
```

returns status code 200 and all information about this user.

I have no idea why GoogleClient fails to verify token? Am I using wrong Client ID?

**EDIT**:
I have found the source of the problem: I have accidentally pasted twice ClientID:

```
'client_id' => 'client-id-tokenclient-id-token'
```

-.-